# ocultar <option> com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom galera tenho 3 `select` no meu código, sendo eles `tipo`, `outros` e `margem`.

Quando eu marco a opção `MARGENS` no `select` `tipo` o `select` `margem` aparece na tela. Até ai tudo ok.

Porem preciso que as opções `some` e `some2` do `select`  do `outros` fiquem ocultas.

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo errado?

```js
function mostraForm(valor) {
  if (valor === "MA") {
    document.getElementById("margem").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("some").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("some2").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("margem").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("some2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("some").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  #margem {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name='tipo' onchange="mostraForm(this.value)">
        <option value='R$'>R$</option>
        <option value='%'>%</option>
        <option value='MA'>MARGENS</option>
      </select>
      
      <select name='outros'>
        <option value='MA'>MARGENS</option>
        <option value='so' id="some">some</option>
        <option value='so2' id="some2">some2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="margem">
    <td>
      <select name='margem'>
        <option value='com'>COMISSÃO</option>
        <option value='des'>DESCONTO</option>
        <option value='cre'>CRÉDITO</option>
      </select>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dentro do primeiro if você precisa setar `none` para os elementos de id `some` e `some2` e no else você precisa setar `block` para os mesmos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O display nas options nem sempre funciona bem, no entanto pode desabilitar essas opções

```js
function mostraForm(valor) {
  if (valor === "MA") {
    document.getElementById("margem").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("some").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("some2").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("margem").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("some2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("some").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  #margem {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name='tipo' onchange="mostraForm(this.value)">
        <option value='R$'>R$</option>
        <option value='%'>%</option>
        <option value='MA'>MARGENS</option>
      </select>
      
      <select name='outros'>
        <option value='MA'>MARGENS</option>
        <option value='so' id="some">some</option>
        <option value='so2' id="some2">some2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="margem">
    <td>
      <select name='margem'>
        <option value='com'>COMISSÃO</option>
        <option value='des'>DESCONTO</option>
        <option value='cre'>CRÉDITO</option>
      </select>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: vlw funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado

Comment: De nada @HugoBorges. Ainda bem